# Remove item from basket

Tags: php

I want to implement a simple link that when clicked, deletes the item from the basket.

How can I do this?

```
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
```

and

```
$paypalBasket[] = array($product['common_name'], $item['prod_type'], $product['price'],    $item['quantity'], number_format($line_cost, 2));
  ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?=$product['common_name'];?></td>
    <td><?=$item['prod_type'];?></td>
    <td><?=$product['price'];?></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' value='<?=$item['quantity'];?>' size='2' /></td>
    <td>&pound;<?=number_format($line_cost, 2);?></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: For your information, in English, it's called a *shopping cart*.

Comment: FYI, in English, read carefully -  if you actually look at what I said, you might find that I did not ask how to carry out the process of a whole shopping cart, I asked about a specific part, the removal of an item.

Comment: @Xeon06 what language is basket????

Comment: Without knowing anything about how your system works this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @PeeHaa I'd assume OP speaks French as his native language. In French, there is no distinction between the words for "basket" and "shopping cart".

Question asker: You're misunderstanding me. I'm not talking about your question at all. Just telling you that the word in English is "shopping cart".

Comment: One of the worst "questions" I've seen here in days

Comment: @Xeon06 uhhhm basket is also used...

Comment: @PeeHaa Perhaps informally, but on a the [Wikipedia disambiguation page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basket_(disambiguation)) I see no reference to a shopping cart. Moreover, on an website user interface, you'll want to use a word that everyone will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point the link href to a script and pass in the id of the item via a query string. Something like this.

```
<a href="delete_item.php?id=1"></a>
```

Then in that script do any necessary validation checks, delete the item then re-show them the shopping cart.